# React / React Router, check if it's the first time navigating to a certain route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my React app, I have this:

1. If you start in the `/` index route, a splash page appears and you can click to close the splash and go to the content of the homepage.
2. If you start on any other route, the splash page does not appear and when you go to the `/` route from these pages, the splash page still doesn't appear.

In both cases, I want to initialize some `window` event listeners on the homepage after they happen (i.e. after you click the splash page or after you navigate to the index page from another page).

Currently, the way I achieve this is by keeping a `loadState` variable in Redux.

1. If I start from the `/` route, clicking the splash page will set the `loadState` to "loaded" and the listeners get set up inside the `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle.
2. If I start from any other route, on `componentDidMount`, the `loadState` will be set to "loaded". Then if I navigate to the `/` route, the listeners get set up on `componentDidMount` because we check if the `loadState` is "loaded."

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid both functions. It would be ideal if `componentWillUpdate` runs on the initial render because then I could avoid having the redundant check inside the `componentWillMount` lifecycle. An even better option would be if React Router has a built-in lifecycle of when a route is initially rendered.

Comment: maybe you can search the route history ?

Comment: what version of react router? in v3 you can add a callback to `browserHistory.listen`

Comment: I agree that is just something they should be built into the router. Even on Github people will advise on workaround using your own state, or even creating another third party package, whereas it makes 100% sense to just push every route into an array as a built-in functionality for the router that is in fact responsible for the routing -.-.